# As admin assign permission to users

Tags: opportunity, permissions, user-management

I am the admin of an app and have created users. I wanna give permission to one of my users to be able to create opportunities. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to upgrade privileges for one user and not everyone with the same profile you can use permission sets. The help doc below will get you started.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=perm_sets_overview.htm